# Finding Constants for a probability density functions given a finite interval

Tags: calculus

Given the probability density function f(x) with constant K on the interval [a,b], how do you solve the value of K?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two requirements for a probability density function $f(x)$ on the interval $[a,b]$:

1) $f(x) \ge 0$ everywhere on the interval

2) $\int_a^b f(x)\, dx = 1$

Comment: Dear Robert Israel, It is my pleasure to have your comments on my question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1560808/quasiconvex-and-lower-semicontinuous-function