# Quasiconvex and lower semicontinuous function

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, optimization

**Definition 1.** Let $X$ be a Banach space and $f:X\rightarrow\overline{\mathbb{R}}$. The function $f$ is said to be proper if $f(x)>-\infty$ for all $x\in X$ and there exists $x_0\in X$ such that $f(x_0)<\infty$.

**Definition 2.** Let $X$ be a Banach space and $f:X\rightarrow\overline{\mathbb{R}}$. The function $f$ is said to be quasiconvex if for every $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ the level set
$$
L_\alpha:=\{x\in X: f(x)\leq\alpha\}
$$
is convex.

**Definition 3.** Let $X$ be a Banach space and $f:X\rightarrow\overline{\mathbb{R}}$. The function $f$ is said to be lower semicontinuous if for every $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ the level set
$$
L_\alpha:=\{x\in X: f(x)\leq\alpha\}
$$
is closed.

**Question.** Let $X$ be a Banach space and $\varphi:X\rightarrow\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ a proper, lower semicontinuous, and quasiconvex function. Let $u,v\in X$ such that $u\ne v$ and $\varphi(u)\leq\varphi(v)$. Suppose that there exists $v^*\in X^*$ such that
$$
\sup_{z\in ]u,v[}\{\varphi(z)+\langle v^*,z\rangle\}>\max\{\varphi(u)+\langle v^*,u\rangle,\varphi(v)+\langle v^*,v\rangle\}.
$$
I would like to know whether there exists $w\in]u,v[$ such that
$$
\forall r>0,\exists w_r\in B_r(w)\bigcap]w,v[: \varphi(w)+\langle v^*,w\rangle\geq \varphi(w_r)+\langle v^*,w_r\rangle.
$$
Thank you for all comments and helping.

Comment: No one helps me to attack this problem.

Comment: Some comments:  1) I think your definition 2 was intended to be "quasiconvex" rather than the stated "convex."  2) I made it through  all but the last math expression, which I cannot understand.  It seems to be a circular statement of the form "there exists a vector $w_r$ in a set that is defined by $w_r$."  Some intuition on what you are trying to do might help.

Comment: It is also not really clear to me what sets are being intersected in that last expression, and what the "such that" means: To me, "All intervals $]w, v[$ such that..." does not really make sense since both $w$ and $v$ have already been fixed (extra conditions "such that" are only useful when there are some options).